# Android AsyncTask Logging in same file

Tags: android, logging, android-asynctask

I have a Log class, i can use it to log every thing from every class to write on a single file..

This works fine.

But i have a lot of async task on my programme and i can have concurence acces to my log class and file how can i protect it to don't have split Log message or error?

Cause if two `Asynctasks` need to log something at the same time i don't know how this works.

I don't know if it's a good idea to log in the same file with multiple thread.

Is concurencial acces to file manage by android or need i to dev some thread lock with mutex like in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When two or more threads need access to a shared resource, they need some way to ensure that the resource will be used by only one thread at a time.

The process by which this **synchronization** is achieved is called **thread synchronization**.

Check out Java synchronization tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Add `synchronized` keyword to your logging function